# Как отправить текст (кириллицу) в google sheets содержащий пробелы?

Tags: google-apps-script

Создал скрипт в https://script.google.com который пишет в А5 и B5 текст через get-запрос:

```js
function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15hEM**скрыл**v88");
  sheet.getRange("A5").setValue(e.parameter.p1);
  sheet.getRange("B5").setValue(e.parameter.p2);
}
```

Отправляю GET запрос:

```js
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxW**скрыл***OH/exec?p1=qwerty&p2=Отправка данных в Google Docs GET запросами
```

Получаю ответ 400 потому что текст **Отправка данных в Google DocsGET запросами** содержит пробелы.

Если убираю пробелы (текст это кириллица),то ответ 200 и такие кракозябры пишет в B5
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, откуда вы отправляете запрос. Судя по тому, что видно только URL, то очень похоже на какое-то php в Win с кодировкой `CP1251`.

Переведите свой файл на стороне инициатора запроса в [нормальную кодировку как все](https://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/character_encoding), и будет все работать.

Для исключения пробелов в строке запроса используются инструменты кодирования строки параметров. Например, для JavaScript это метод [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Без понимания того, как вы делаете запрос, лучше ответа не получить.

Comment: Спасибо. Написал такой JS
const uri = [[B_TITLE]];
const encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri);

[[ENCODED]] = encoded;


В перем [[B_TITLE]] находится как пример: Отправка данных в Google Docs GET запросами

На выходе имеем в [[ENCODED]] такое уже сконверченное: %D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0

Comment: О, круто! Это решение. Спасибо!